# How to recursively reverse a circular linked list?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

```
Node* reverseRecursive(Node* node)
{
    if(node->next == head ) {
        return node;
    }

    auto res = reverseRecursive(node->next);
    node->next->next = node;
    // one line is missing here
    return res;
}
```

This is what I have done so far.

Comment: Reversing a list does not require recursion at all.

Comment: This isn't the kind of problem you want to solve recursively, you'll likely get a stack overflow.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "This is what I have done so far." Okay, and what specfically is your question about it? What happens when you try your code? How is that different from what is supposed to happen? In your own words, what do you think are the remaining logical steps to solve the problem; and exactly where and why are you stuck with it?

Comment: "// one line is missing here" This comment is suspicious. Did someone give you this code, and ask you to fill in the correct line in that spot? In that case, please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822).

Comment: With the one line missing, this would fit better in puzzling.SE

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution:

```
Node* reverseRecursive(Node* node) {
    if(node->next == head ) {
        return node;
    }

    auto res = reverseRecursive(node->next);
    node->next->next = node;
    node->next = res;
    return res;
}
```

Assigning the next pointer to the last node was that remaining line .